# Why can't Scala infer the type of Map(1 -> 2).toSet.map(_._2), and it can with `filter`

Tags: scala

The following code results in Scala compiler fails to infer the type of the `_` placeholder

```
Map(1 -> 2).toSet.map(_._2)
<console>:11: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1._2)
       Map(1 -> 2).toSet.map(_._2)
```

in a similar example with a `filter` function, Scala type inference works well:

```
Map(1 -> 2).toSet.filter(_._2 > 2)
res6: scala.collection.immutable.Set[(Int, Int)] = Set()
```

I'm using Scala 2.11.7.

Comment: Probably has to do with `map` taking an implicit CBF.

Comment: @elyse yes, that's exactly why I used `map` with CBF and `filter` with no CBF. :-) But that doesn't explain why the type inferencer fails.